# Rails Dry up Find or Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following method in my model which uses `find_or_create_by` to find or create a new product.

```
 def self.save_prod(product)
 Product.find_or_create_by_prod_id(product)
       product_data = ItemData.get_product_data(product)
       p.update_attributes(
       :prod_id => product,
       :upc => product_data[:upc],
       :title => product_data[:title]
       )
   end
```

The `ItemData.get_product_data()` method is a module method which calls an API to fetch product data:

```
def self.get_product_data(product)
       url_raw = URI.parse("http://www.api.com/v1/itemid=#{product}")
            url = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_raw).body 
            @resp = JSON.parse(url) 
            @title = Sanitize.clean(@resp["serviceResult"]["itemName"]).strip
            @upc = @resp["serviceResult"]["uPC"]
            {:title => @title, :upc => @upc}
    end
```

This works as expected, however I know it can be a LOT more efficient, by not calling the `ItemData.get_product_data()` method every time the `save_prod()` method is called. How can I add new product data without having to call the `ItemData.get_product_data()` if a product already exists.

Comment: is the returned value of the API call nothing but a Product object ??
what is p in the p.update attributes here ?

Comment: the API call return product data (title and upc). the product object is created in the `save_prod` method.

Comment: Check my answer below. Why do you want to make an API call for the object which you are creating just now ? Are you creating empty objects in Product.find_or_create ?

Comment: I need to make the API call to create the object, because without calling the API, I wouldnt have the attributes need to save the product object. Im trying to avoid calling the API only if the product already exists, however if the product does not exist, I have to call the API.

Comment: Ahh ok ill modify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to doing it. This would return the `Product` object if it is already present otherwise it will create it from api and return the new object.

```
def self.save_prod(product)
     Product.find_by_prod_id(product) || Product.create( ItemData.get_product_data(product) ) 
end
```

Modify the api call to return a hash with `prod_id`. Not sure why you are converting `title` and `upc` to class variables here. It could lead to problems if they are used extensively.

```
def self.get_product_data(product)
   url_raw = URI.parse("http://www.api.com/v1/itemid=#{product}")
        url = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_raw).body 
        @resp = JSON.parse(url) 
        @title = Sanitize.clean(@resp["serviceResult"]["itemName"]).strip
        @upc = @resp["serviceResult"]["uPC"]
        {:title => @title, :upc => @upc, :prod_id => product}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a find or create use find or initialize by . Change your code to following :

```
prod = find_or_initialize_by_prod_id(product)
if prod.new_record?
  prod.save!
  product_data = ItemData.get_product_data(product)
   prod.update_attributes(
   :prod_id => product,
   :upc => product_data[:upc],
   :title => product_data[:title]
   )
end
```

by using find_or_initalize you can distinguish whether the record was created or found by using new_record method. If new you can save and make an API call and do whatever you want.